# Two ways to test a hypothesized proportion against data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I would like to conduct a test whether my hypothesised proportion `P` (a estimated parameter) is greater or equal to the sample proportion $P_{0}$. The hypothesis is as follows:

\begin{align}
H_{0}\!: P \ge P_{0}  \\
H_{1}\!: P <  P_{0}
\end{align}

I believe this is a right-tailed, one-sided hypothesis test, given $H_{0}$.  Namely, we are looking whether the result of the test is greater or equal to 95% or 99% ($\alpha = 5\%$ and/or $1\%$).

Let's suppose that my parameter estimate $P$ is 0.15, hence 15% of population fails. The sample has 1000 obs and failures of 16% (160 failures and 840 successes).  I could solve it two ways:

1. Build confidence interval around the predicted value $P$ and test whether the $P_{0} = 16\%$ is above the upper bound CI.

   In this case the upper CI is, using R:

   ```
   qbeta(.95, 0.15*1000, 1000-(0.15*1000))
   # [1] 0.1689547
   ```

   Since 16% < then 16.90% we *fail to reject* the $H_{0}$ hypothesis.
2. The second option is using the `pbeta` function:

   ```
   1-pbeta(0.15, 160, 840)
   # [1] 0.8045226
   ```

   Here we have the right tail hypothesis test, where 0.15 is the $P$ estimated parameter (our forecast) and `160` is number of observed failures and 840 successes (1000obs - 160 failures).

   With the result of `80.04%` and fact that `80.04%` < `95%` we fail to reject the null hypothesis (hence accept $H_{0}$).

Are the formulations and solutions correct?

Comment: The questio is vague and adds to the confusion. Try to be exact  by explaoining after reading of text

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the question is vague or unclear. I have provided formulation and solution, and I would like to have opinion whether its correct or wrong.

Comment: I am not sure whether we can postulate a  null hypothesis  more than or equal tto in the third paragraph.

Comment: well, the hypothesis as it is has been set and fixed by someone else in fact. So I have to find a solution around this hypothesis.

Comment: I don't see what is unclear about this question (although it could be cleaned up a bit). Voting to leave open.